# Thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes. What does that mean?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I was going through Javadoc for CountDownLatch, I came across a line in the documentation for await method.

> If the current count is greater than zero then the current thread
>   becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant

What is meant by `current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes` here?

Comment: It means the scheduler won't attempt to let the thread run, because it's not ready to run.

Comment: Sorry to both you. I could not understand it properly. Can you throw some light on this??

Comment: A thread runs when it is in runnable state and the scheduler schedules it. When a threads is disabled for scheduling, it will not get its share of cpu cycles, so it wont run.

Comment: IMO, the language you cite is _very_ misleading.  It would be better if it described `await()` from the point-of-view of the calling thread instead of describing how the operating system implements it.  From the calling thread's point-of-view it's simple:  `await()` does not return until other threads bring the count down to zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a given system, only a fixed number of threads can actually execute at the same time (you're limited by the number of cores in the machine.) When there are more threads to run than there are cores, the thread scheduler will cycle through the threads in some fashion, giving each a bit of time on the CPU.

However, in some cases it doesn't make sense to give a thread time on the CPU. For example, if a thread acquires a countdown latch whose total is greater than zero, then that thread is stuck waiting for other threads to also acquire the latch. It therefore doesn't make any sense to let that thread have any CPU time, since the thread is just sitting and waiting for other threads. Therefore, typically, the scheduler would not even attempt to give the thread any CPU time, preferring instead to schedule other threads that can still make progress. Once enough threads do acquire the countdown latch, all threads that were blocked this way are then put back into the scheduler for further consideration.

In other words, the thread stops running and the scheduler will intelligently not waste time trying to run it until the latch is ready.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent explanation. You nailed it!!

Comment: 1. then How scheduler will come to know that thread has been enabled again.
2. what is the code mechanism to make a thread dormant in java ?

Comment: @praveenjain For (1), the thread scheduler also implements locks, monitors, etc., so when a lock becomes free it can wake up the threads. For (2), that depends on your JVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the code in that thread will not go any further until latch.countDown() is called on the same latch from other threads thereby making the latch count 0.

A thread runs when it is in runnable state and the scheduler schedules it. When a threads is disabled for scheduling, it will not get its share of cpu cycles, so it wont run which means its program counter will not increase. Its stack will freeze where it was till it gets the cpu again.